# how to insert \Delta with normal text

Tags: symbols

If I do

```
The equation is \Delta I/I= k = constant,
```

I get

Missing $ inserted.
 
                $
l.26 The equation is \Delta

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is the delta symbol in question $\Delta$.
\end{document}
```